# Exiting Python closes SSH connection and can't return to Bash shell

Tags: python, bash

I was trying to install python 3.6 and automate a pip install, however, I have somehow locked/defaulted my command window to Python. Any attempt to exit using exit() or quit() will close my SSH connection, how do i fix this so I can get my bash shell back?

Comment: Any chance you're using `exec python` to start it? That makes bash *immediately* exit, and replace itself with Python, so at that point bash isn't even running any longer.

Comment: Regardless, we'd need a [mcve] giving us enough detail to reproduce what you did ourselves to be able to provide a certain answer.

Comment: BTW, what you *might* consider doing is starting a new shell as a child process of your Python interpreter... or even just an editor. f/e, `os.execlp('vim', 'vim', '.')` will replace the Python interpreter with vim, and you can load your dotfiles in it and undo whatever damage was done.

Comment: I wanted ansible to handle scl enable : 
#!/bin/bash
. /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable
. /opt/python-venv/bin/activate
exec python "$@"

Comment: Yeah, `exec python` tells your shell to exit. Don't ever do that in your dotfiles: After it's happened, the shell is no longer running at all, so it's impossible to exit back to it.

Comment: This is what its defaulting to on any SSH connection, being a newbie, i can for the life of me get back to bash or even know how to:

Python 3.6.3 (default, Jan  9 2018, 10:19:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: What would the best way be to disable the exec python and get back to bash from here?

Comment: See the `os.execlp()` command I suggested earlier.

Comment: BTW, if it's ansible code you ran that set your dotfiles up this way, [edit]ing that code into the question would be a step towards providing a proper MCVE -- that way we can tell which specific dotfiles were modified.

Comment: Thanks again, i can access the files using os.execlp. This was run in ansible and the two files previously listed were the only ones. Just need to determine which specific files needs to be changed so that I can reverse the path exec python condition.

Comment: Again, if you showed us your ansible code, we'd have an idea of which files it changed. Right now, there aren't enough details in this question to permit an answer.

Comment: sorry about that,
name: Create python36 enable script file
    copy:
      dest: "/etc/profile.d/python36enable.sh"
      content: |
       #!/bin/bash
       . /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable
       . /opt/python-venv/bin/activate exec python "$@"

Comment: [edit] into the question, don't comment with code -- the comments drop all the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To undo the destruction caused by your Ansible code, you can run (as a user with suitable privileges):

```
os.unlink('/etc/profile.d/python36enable.sh')
```

...and in the future, don't ever include an `exec` command inside `/etc/profile.d/*` (or other dotfile content).

Comment: Thanks Charles, this resolved the issue. Ill make sure to avoid that ill-fated mistake!